# What are pthread_cond negative aspects aside from clustering code

Tags: c, thread-safety, pthreads

sorry if the question has already been asked, I couldn't find it through the many questions concerning pthread_conds in a different way.

As for my question, I searched my best and, although I found many post, articles and questions about the way to use pthread_cond, when to use them and their difference in contrast to semaphore, most of the people would justify the [not using of] pthread_cond like so: `you don't need it`, and I've never seen any backside of pthread_cond vars clearly stated.

Lately, I've been told the same concerning a problem with a multiple-producers/single-consumer queue where there shouldn't be any thirst on either sides.

I was first tempted to use pthread_cond even on the producing side, but only because they usually are pretty handy and not because of a proper thorough evaluation of the options.

Which made me wonder: *Had I ended up using pthread_cond instead of simple mutexes to insert data into my queue, what would the consequences (aside from me producing some extra code) have been on my program runtime, if any? Is the difference really just about (small) change in code size and memory usage?*

Thanks,

Comment: When choosing an appropriate synchronization primitive, code size and memory usage are almost never considerations. it's more about simplicity and what most naturally reflects the specific use case's nature. It's so easy to get this code wrong that the most important consideration is usually keeping the code simple enough to be "obviously correct". It'll still be wrong, but that's the best you can do.

Comment: So in my case, since that's what came up naturally and I'm the only one working with this code, the right answer would be `pthread_cond vars  are always right and have no negative aspect`?

Comment: Anytime you feel something is always right or always wrong, you are always wrong :)   Absolutes are the exception, the normal is let the right answer be heard.

Comment: Thread programming is challenging and fun, and VERY hard. Learn the basics well, and keep your code as simple as possible. Condition variables and mutexes are fundamentally different. Read manpages and examples, and use condvars as they are intended to be used! If you can, use the benefits of RAII and C++ wrappers on top of pthreads.